# Conditional contribution for `activitybar` in `viewsContainers`

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to conditionally create a contribution to the `activitybar` section for a `viewContainer` for my extension [code review](https://github.com/d-koppenhagen/vscode-code-review).

I thought it can my be achieved by adding this section to the `package.json` file:

```json
"viewsContainers": {
      "activitybar": [
        {
          "id": "code-review",
          "title": "Code Review",
          "icon": "images/icon-sidebar.svg",
          "when": "codeReview:displayCodeReviewExplorer"
        }
      ]
    },
```

But unfortunately it seems not to work as the view is always displayed and the `when` part seems not to be executed.

Here is the commit I created:

https://github.com/d-koppenhagen/vscode-code-review/commit/aa13034533bc5dd2a5a8bb2743db60505cd3bd52

So the general goal is to just activate the view when a specific file is present.
Otherwise, the view and of course the activitybar button should not be visible.

Any hint / suggestions / solution? PR's are also very welcome 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what if you hard code true/false values for `setContext` call does the `when` test work for ViewContainers

Comment: same result unfortunately. I#ve also tried `"when": "false"` without success

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed it with this commit:
https://github.com/d-koppenhagen/vscode-code-review/commit/830a7b922ec0e89fdaa75b4966a5348ffe84388d

The `when` clause must be part of the `views` section instead of `viewsContainers`  -> `activityBar`:

```json
"viewsContainers": {
      "activitybar": [
        {
          "id": "code-review",
          "title": "Code Review",
          "icon": "images/icon-sidebar.svg"
        }
      ]
    },
    "views": {
      "code-review": [
        {
          "id": "code-review.list",
          "name": "Comment Explorer",
          "when": "codeReview:displayCodeReviewExplorer"
        }
      ]
    },
```